# Create a Matrix using Table and RandomReal

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

[image]

I am trying to create a Matrix 4x4 with elements from [-1,1], using the commands RandomReal and Table. When I am trying to use the command Table, I destroy my code.
Any advice?

Comment: I don't understand, why do you need to use Table[] ? Apparently your code is working...

Comment: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2710921

Comment: You could also write: Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {i, 4}, {j, 4}] to get the random matrix, though it's not simpler than RandomReal[{-1,1},{4,4}]

Comment: Please directly  post the Mathematica code in  the input frame.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The different methods produce identical results

```
SeedRandom[1234];

tab1 = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 4, 4];

SeedRandom[1234];

tab2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}];

SeedRandom[1234];

tab3 = Array[RandomReal[{-1, 1}] &, {4, 4}];

tab1 === tab2 === tab3

(* True *)
```